# Is the Master Criminal achievement broken?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, pc, steam, achievements

I've completed all achievements so far, except the `Master Criminal` one, where you're supposed to have a bounty of `1000` gold or higher in each hold at the same time:

1. Eastmarch *(Windhelm)*
2. Falkreath
3. Haafingar *(Solitude)*
4. Hjaalmarch *(Morthal)*
5. The Pale *(Dawnstar)*
6. The Reach *(Markarth)*
7. The Rift *(Riften)*
8. Whiterun
9. Winterhold

My plan was to kill a random person in each city in front of the guards to instantly get the required bounty and run away afterwards.

Doing exactly that, paying attention that I'll definitely get the bounty popup, does not unlock that achievement though.

**Am I doing something wrong? Is this a *(known)* bug?**

*All that is done with the latest version of Skyrim `(1.3.7.0)` on the PC using Steam and being online.*

---

**New:** It was a bug indeed.

> Master Criminal achievement/trophy unlocks properly in French, German, Spanish and Italian
>   *([Source](http://www.bethblog.com/2012/01/23/now-on-steam-beta-update-for-skyrim/))*

Comment: Why not check your bounties to make sure you actually have 1000+ in each hold? Look under the Crime tab of your statistics.

Comment: @RavenDreamer - I verified that, my total bounty increased by `9000` _Septims_, and the guards in each city demanded over the required amount.

Comment: It should list the individual cities if you have a current bounty. I.e., "Haafinger Bounty: 1000; Whiterun Bounty: 1000", etc.

Comment: @RavenDreamer All individual bounties are `0`, no matter what I am doing. Guards asking for the correct amount though.

Comment: Strange. FWIW, I did this achievement just now, with the same version number and same strategy (fast-travel to town, throw some fireballs, run away while Shadowmere tanks). I had no problem with it. Nonetheless, it seems like a [vanishingly small percentage](http://steamcommunity.com/stats/TheElderScrollsVSkyrim/achievements/) (0.6%) have succeeded on Steam, so I'm wondering if there might be a glitch.

Comment: this bug evidenced itself for me on the english version of the game as well.  i'm trying the language pack now.

Comment: Now fixed in 1.4 patch released yesterday

Comment: Every time I just finish the master criminal achievement... my game crashes. There is definitely something wrong with the achievement!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the release version of the game there was a bug on any non-english client that just wouldn't allow anyone get the achivement.  I had a lot of trouble getting this to work, I switched my client's to english and back, and at some point I was awarded.  If your client is not in english, you should definetly try switching.